# Capture bash output in a python array

Tags: python, arrays, bash, scripting, python-2.6

I have a bash script that needs to be converted to a python program.

I run a command and capture its output in bash array and iterate through it.

```
diskArr=(`lsblk | grep 'disk' | awk -v col1=1 '{print $col1}'`)
```

The command gives me a list of all HDD's in the system and stores it in the array "diskArr".

I have tried using os.system and subprocess.Popen and haven't been successful.

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
lsblk | grep 'disk' | awk -v col1=1 '{print $col1}'
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['lsblk', '|', 'grep', 'disk', '|', 'awk', '-v', 'col1=1', '{print $col1}']
>>>
>>>
>>> subprocess.Popen(args)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f8e083ce590>
>>> lsblk: invalid option -- 'v'

Usage:
 lsblk [options] [<device> ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, you aren't actually converting the program to python, you're just trying to use python as a wrapper to the shell. But you can do the grepping and awking in python too:

```
import subprocess
import re

lsblk = subprocess.Popen(['lsblk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in lsblk.stdout:
    if 'disk' in line:
        parts = re.split(r'\s+', line.strip())
        name, majmin, rm, size, ro, devtype = parts[:6]
        if len(parts) > 6:
            mountpoint = parts[6]
        else:
            mountpoint = None
        print(majmin)
returncode = lsblk.wait()
if returncode:
    print("things got bad. real bad.")
```

That's just one example. If you want a list of lines that refer to disks, you could build a list that holds lines that have 'disk' in them:

```
lsblk = subprocess.Popen(['lsblk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
blockdevs = [line.strip() for line in lsblk.stdout if 'disk' in line]
returncode = lsblk.wait()
if returncode:
    print("things got bad. real bad.")
print(blockdevs)
```

Comment: Can you explain this line? parts = re.split(r'\s+', line.strip())

Comment: It splits the line into parts like awk, using python's regular expression module *re*. `re.split(r'\s+', 'sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk')` creates a list: `['sda', '8:0', '0', '232.9G', '0', 'disk']`.

Comment: Okay, If I do print(name) I ge all the device names. But how do I iterate through it? How do I store it in an Array?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, but I'll update the answer with one option. BTW, my awk foo is not so good, but on closer inspection its completely unnecessary in this case. `lsblk | grep disk` does the same thing.

Comment: If you did the "-1" can you please explain it?

Comment: I didn't do the -1. I was curious about that too.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [replacing the shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#replacing-shell-pipeline) in the official documentation, it has a good example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: In the example you suggested(17.5.4.2), what does this line do? output = p2.communicate()[0]

Comment: If you did the "-1" can you please explain it?